# Windows 8 Store: Denied DocumentsLibrary Access during certification

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I am building a suite of apps that rely on each other's data.
I wanted to put this shared data repository in the Documents library folder.

However, when I attempt to submit the app to the Windows 8 store, I am denied access to that folder location.

I have a developer account which does not qualify for DocumentLibrary access.
I was told that because I am not a company, I do not qualify for a company account.

How can I share application data with my other apps when offline?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, one of the differences between company/individual accounts is access to the Document Library (full list of differences [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jennifer/archive/2012/09/18/what-is-the-difference-between-a-company-vs-individual-account-for-the-windows-store.aspx)).

If offline is a requirement, one option is SQLLite.  See Tim's post on it [here](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2012/08/07/updated-how-to-using-sqlite-from-windows-store-apps.aspx).

If online is sufficient, Windows Azure Mobile Services is pretty awesome for throwing up a quick and easy database backend.  More details [here](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/).

Comment: Thank you for your advice. However, I am already using SQLite. I want the db file to be available to all of my other Windows 8 apps. Having this data isolated in an app data folder does not resolve my needs when building an enterprise solution where data needs to be accessed by other clients as well.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Store apps run in a sandboxed environment, isolated from each other, therefore they can't easily share their data.

If having a custom online service that both apps can connect to for sharing data between them is not enough, then you'll need the user to select a folder (from both apps) where the shared data will be stored. This way you'll be able to access it.

First use [`FolderPicker`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker.aspx) for the user to select the folder:

```
var picker = new FolderPicker();
picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".sqldb");
var folder = await picker.PickSingleFolderAsync();
```

Then add the folder to [`FutureAccessList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.accesscache.storageapplicationpermissions.futureaccesslist.aspx) so that you'll keep the access to it even after the app gets restarted:

```
var token = StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.Add(folder);
```

You need to store the `token` so that you can load it next time. [`LocalSettings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.applicationdata.localsettings.aspx) would be a suitable location. When your app is run again, you first read the token and with it regain access to the selected folder:

```
var folder = await StorageApplicationPermissions.FutureAccessList.GetFolderAsync(token);
```

I know this is not a perfect solution since it needs user intervention to setup everything correctly, but I think it's the only way to make such data sharing between apps possible. Even so, you might have a hard time certifying the app with this functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your guidance. Does FilePicker support default paths so that I can guide users to the intended db file?

Comment: @ScottNimrod Try using [`SuggestedStartLocation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.pickers.folderpicker.suggestedstartlocation.aspx) property

Comment: Thanks for your help. SuggestedStartLocation is not guaranteed to work as a default. I'm afraid I cannot mark this as an answer. This post will document this issue as a Windows 8 policy failure.